# Concatenation within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to have something like this in my stored procedure:

```
InvoiceNumber =  EventCode + EventInstance + EventCount
```

I am not quite sure how to code this into my setup (see below). I have tried many ideas but no luck.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInvoiceNumber]
   @EventCode nvarchar(10),
   @EventInstance nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Payment (EventCode, EventInstance, EventCount) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.EventCode, INSERTED.EventInstance, INSERTED.EventCount
        SELECT 
            @EventCode, @EventInstance, ISNULL(MAX(EventCount), -1) + 1
        FROM 
            Payment 
        WHERE 
            (EventCode = @EventCode AND
             EventInstance = @EventInstance)
END
```

Comment: Create an output parameter for your stored procedure

Comment: @cha Could you provide an example?

Comment: Do you mean just adding another line to your OUTPUT? e.g. `INSERTED.EventCode + INSERTED.EventInstance + INSERTED.EventCount InvoiceNumber`?

Comment: @cha InvoiceNumber is empty. I need to take the data from the SELECT statement (EventCode, EventInstance, and EventCount) and concatenate it to give me the InvoiceNumber. Then I want to INSERT EventCode, EventInstance, EventCount, and InvoiceNumber into my Payment table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Payment (EventCode, EventInstance, EventCount, InvoiceNumber) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.EventCode, INSERTED.EventInstance, 
           INSERTED.EventCount, INSERTED.InvoiceNumber
    SELECT @EventCode, @EventInstance, 
           isnull(max(EventCount),-1) + 1,
           EventCode + EventInstance + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), isnull(max(EventCount),-1) + 1)
    FROM   Payment 
    WHERE (EventCode = @EventCode AND
        EventInstance = @EventInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInvoiceNumber]
        @EventCode nvarchar(10),
        @EventInstance nvarchar(10)
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @InvoiceNumber nvarchar(30) 

    declare @EventCount INT = 
    (select isnull(max(EventCount),-1) + 1
      FROM Payment 
      WHERE (EventCode = @EventCode AND
        EventInstance = @EventInstance)
    )

    SELECT @InvoiceNumber = @EventCode + @EventInstance + convert(nvarchar(10),@EventCount)

    INSERT INTO Payment (EventCode, EventInstance, EventCount, InvoiceNumber) 
    SELECT @EventCode, @EventInstance, @EventCount, @InvoiceNumber

END
```